# Laravel Error 500 in Controller when using mail()

Tags: email, laravel

I am sending a AJAX POST Request to my Controller @ReservatioNController@send.
It is working without any problems, but when using mail() it always resolves in a 500-Error.

```
class ReservationController extends Controller
{
    public function send(Request $request)
    {
        $adulte = $request->no_adulte;
        $enfant = $request->no_enfant;
        $animal = $request->no_animal;
        $vehicule = $request->no_vehicule;
        $msg = "Test! $adulte - $enfant - $animal - $vehicule";

        mail('abc@abc.abc', 'ReservationTest', $msg, 'From: abc@abc.abc');
        return 1;
    }
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be your mail settings in the .env file. Also, try checking your log files for more details.

Comment: Hm, currently using WampServer to try things out. Log says `ailed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25` but phpinfo() says that mailserver in fact is localhost and the port is 25, so these settings should be right.

Comment: Oh, alright. It is because local servers dont server mailservers. After using a tool called "Test Mail Server Tool" which listens to port 25, it works. So appearently it will also work on the server afterwards. Thank you.